# I have a list of requirements I am looking to fill -- Can CiviCRM do these?

Tags: evaluating-civicrm

Thanks for the help. Our organization, and registration is fairly complex. We have three branches: volunteers, athletics, and scouting. All branches support all ages. We have one general membership fee that covers all members (except volunteers, of course), and as a member you could be in any and all branches. So here is what we need a system to do...

- One account to manage multiple members (i.e. parent creating an account to create 2 memberships for his children)
- Householding
- Setting primary contact (i.e. for members under 18, a parent is the primary contact; for members 18+ they are their own contact)
- The membership application needs to include two file uploads (that can be extracted/downloaded)
- Member group - we (admin) need to have the ability to assign each
  member to individual groups like "Boys Basketball age 5-7 Team 1" and
  "Boy scouts troop 2". Again each member might be in more than one
  group
- The ability to filter and contact by groups above. That is we need to be able to filter to everyone in basketball, or everyone in basketball on 5-7 age teams, etc
- Ability to create an event calendar by each group/team
- Process yearly membership dues
- Ability to filter for and contact unpaid members

So I think this is most everything -- please let me know if you need clarity on the above.

Answer (score 5):

CiviCRM can do all the things you described above, with two caveats:

- Some of the requests you're making around primary contact and one account managing multiple members work in CiviCRM with any CMS - but if your CMS isn't Drupal, you'll end up with some clunky public-facing data entry.  Stack Exchange is littered with people asking how to do forms like you're describing in WordPress and are largely disappointed.  If you're starting fresh, definitely use CiviCRM atop Drupal, and use Webform-CiviCRM integration to handle your public-facing forms.
- Ditto the calendar - a WordPress or Joomla person can tell me if I'm wrong, but if you want a calendar in a calendar view (instead of, e.g., an events listing) I think you need Drupal.
- Finally - you're right, this is definitely a complicated setup, no matter what CRM you choose!  I would dissuade most people new to CiviCRM from attempting something this complex on their first go-round.  Consider hiring someone, or be prepared for a challenge!

Fortunately, several of the items you're requesting (grouping into multiple groups, searching/contacting by groups, file uploads, processing membership dues, filtering for/contacting unpaid members) are all pretty out-of-the-box.  In fact, all of this is doable out-of-the-box (except the calendar, which requires a Drupal module), but the devil's in the details - specifically in the public-facing form details.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tips Jon -- especially re: Wordpress vs Drupal!!!

Comment: I second what Jon says. You may also find a civi-shop that is willing to 'mentor' rather than to 'build'. In terms of a Drupal calendar View - there is one for civi events you can grab here - http://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/simple-view-showing-civi-events-calendar